# SwiftUI - An unusual use for NavigationView (or stack)

Tags: swiftui, navigationview

I'm trying to build an interface that has a list on the bottom of the screen, with a detail view on the top. Sort of like this:

[Here's a shot of a UI mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DvMb.png)

So when you click on an entry in the list in the bottom rectangle, corresponding data would be displayed in the top. Is there a way to get a NavigationView to do this?

I've got a scheme working without navigationView but I'm running into all sorts of problems with CoreData, because without a normal View hierarchy in place, it seems that passing data between the two gets very confusing.

Comment: You can’t use NavigationView for this, it is a pretty standard setup. Without a sample we can’t help you figure out the issues it shouldn’t be hard to implement.

Comment: Whoops! I had an image that I'd uploaded but for some reason it's not showing up. Lemme see if I can get it in there...

Comment: just pass data in normal way